# How to render async AND dynamic component in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use a combination of async and dynamic components in my app, so far it looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <component
    v-for="(component, index) in components"
    :key="index"
    :is="component.name"
    :data="component"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    component1: () => import(`@/components/component1.vue`),
    component2: () => import(`@/components/component2.vue`)
  }
}
</script>
```

This works but I'm trying to avoid having to manually import all my components individually.

I tried replacing `:is` with a method:

**:is="getComponent(component)"**

```
<script>
  //...
  methods: {
    getComponent(component) {
      const componentName = component.name;

      return () => import(`@/components/${componentName}.vue`);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Which works initially but then the browser gets stuck using a lot of memory, as if it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Any advice? I'm using NUXT but I think this is also applies for vanilla VueJS apps.

Comment: I would import all the components globally, so that they are available everywhere

Comment: I considered that but it would be nice to be able to import them asynchronously so they're not part of the main bundle and only included when needed.

Comment: I guess you want to lazy load your components, I found an article https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/async-vuejs-components/. Hope it will help